# Forcing a user to authenticate using a pop-up

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, popup, zurb-foundation

I have a page I want only authenticated users can come to. Also I want to authenticate them **using a pop-up** when they come to that page, say, twitter bootsrap or foundation. How can I do that if a user can just close it? It's unreliable, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a risk that the user changes the css properties of your live page, to make it invisible pop-up. A simple tool like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/firebug/) makes this possible. Authentications pages are safer in a page intended for this purpose.